# Что означает слово "убо"?

Tags: лексика

В старославянских текстах часто попадает слово "убо". По контексту никак не могу сообразить, что оно значит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Убо** - из церк.-слав. 'итак, посему, следовательно, стало быть'; 'ибо, так как, потому что'.